# buggy animation on ng-repeat (animates wrong element)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have added some animation on element removal for `ng-repeat` item and what follows is it duplicates the last element of the list and applies the animation on it instead of the deleted one.

Why the animation isn't applied on the removed element but instead on the last one duplicated ?

Full code example: https://jsfiddle.net/8bhyv1b4/

**Controller**:

```
$scope.selectedImgs = [];

$scope.deleteImg = function() {
  $scope.selectedImgs.forEach(function(selectedImgIndex, i) {
    // remove image by index 
    $scope.imgs.splice(selectedImgIndex - i, 1);
  });
  $scope.selectedImgs = [];
}

$scope.toggleImg = function(index) {
  var i = $scope.selectedImgs.indexOf(index);
  if (i + 1) {
    $scope.selectedImgs.splice(i, 1);
  } else {
    $scope.selectedImgs.push(index);
    $scope.selectedImgs.sort(function sortNumber(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
  }
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

**Template**:

```
<section class="txtcent">
  <img-row class="blk clearfix" size="imgs.length" ontoggle="toggleImg" selected="selectedImgs">
    <section ng-repeat="url in imgs track by $index" class="inlblk frameimg">
      <div>
        <img width="150" ng-src="{{url}}" />
      </div>
    </section>
  </img-row>
  <span class="noimgmsg" ng-if="!imgs.length">Add images</span>
</section>
```

**CSS**:

```
.frameimg.ng-leave{
  -webkit-animation: 3s removeImgItem;
}
@-webkit-keyframes removeImgItem {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Appreciate your kind help

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? I don't see any question there.

Comment: @Aides Why the animation isn't applied on the removed element but instead it copies the last element and animates it?

Comment: Do you copy those elements yourself or are you just removing one item from the collection?

Comment: @Aides I am just removing an item from the collection.

Comment: Will need some more time figuring this out - btw. what is the purpose of this directive anyway? It seems to be really overcomplicated (also the jquery dependency would probably not be needed for such a task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by `track by $index` and is a relatively old [news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432584/ng-animate-animate-wrong-item-when-using-track-by-index-in-ng-repeat).

You can keep a track of it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14501)

Comment: Thanks, same issue and fixed it because of track by $index

Answer (score 0):

use angular promises. your $defer object should be solved after animation finish; then delete your item from array that ng-repeat displays.

Sum up: First do the animation THEN (on promise solve) delete your element.

Here you have $q (deferred) object docs:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```
promiseOfFinishedAnimation.then(function() {
  deleteElementFromArrayThatNGRepeatDisplays();
});
```

Your problem is coused by deleting item before animation is executed. You execute animation on array item that doesn't exist.

Comment: promises are not easy to understand at first attempt but i hope you try to solve that problem with promises - they will be very useful for you in future