# Angular ng-repeat updates view, but not correctly, on changing array size

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know the title of the question is familiar on SO. I went through many questions and tried their solutions but somehow I am still stuck.

Well I have an array `A` which is being repeated to form a row of input boxes. I have a got a ADD button to add a new row where I basically push a dummy element to this array (so that its length increases and one more row is displayed on UI). The data from input box is stored in the array `A` itself at row's `$index`.

Well, this all works fine. But when I remove a row (I have another button to remove it). While removing I pass the `$index` of the row and do a `splice` at that index.

What I expected was that the element at this index will be removed, which will result in removal of this row from UI. But what's really happening is:

The element gets removed from array `A` and one row gets removed from UI too. But its not the row where REMOVE button was clicked. Rather the last row is removed from UI (regardless of where you click REMOVE).

I am clueless what's going wrong ? Found various similar question, tried many things, but nothing worked :(

Below is relevant code, In this code `home` is the alias of the controller i.e. `controllerAs : home`:

```
<div ng-repeat= "d in home.degrees track by $index" class="inline_block name_container">
         <div class="inline_block aw_div_first">
          <label>College/University/Board:</label></br>
          <input class="form-control pd-forms" type="text"  ng-model="home['degree'][$index]['college']" placeholder="College/University/Board"/>
         </div>
         <div class="inline_block aw_div">
          <label>Qualification:</label></br>
          <input class="form-control pd-forms" type="text"  ng-model="home['degree'][$index]['qual']" placeholder="Qualification"/>
         </div>
         <div class="inline_block aw_div">
          <label>Passing Year:</label></br>
          <input class="form-control pd-forms" type="text"  ng-model="home['degree'][$index]['year']" placeholder="Passing Year"/>
         </div>
         <div class="btn btn-primary inline_block aw_button" ng-click="home.addDegree($index, home['degree'][$index])" ng-if="$index === home.degrees.length - 1">+</div>
         <div class="btn btn-primary inline_block aw_button" ng-click="home.removeDegree($index)" ng-if="($index <= home.degrees.length - 1) && home.degrees.length > 1">-</div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
vm.degrees = [1]; //initialising array with one element to show one row initially

function addDegree(i, data){
            var degree ={};
            degree.college = data.college;
            degree.qual = data.qual;
            degree.year = data.year;
            vm.degrees[i] = degree;
            vm.degrees.push(1);
            console.log("current degrees : ", vm.degrees);
        }

        function removeDegree(i){
            vm.degrees.splice(i,1);
        }
```

Comment: As my first guess, I tried a $scope.$apply() after doing splice. But this gives `$apply already in progress` error

Comment: Can you post a plunker with the code? I tried but there are some errors

Comment: Rejs has posted a plunker in his answer below. It shows the error exactly.

Comment: Remove `track by $index` from your ng-repeat. See [this related issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432584/ng-animate-animate-wrong-item-when-using-track-by-index-in-ng-repeat) for details.

Comment: @noppa : thanks for the link..Can't believe that after so much head-scratching, its the issue with track by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , its working.

DEMO: [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/6mbGKDPcE0o6aZoCyER0?p=preview)

```
 <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as home">
    <div ng-repeat= "d in home.degrees track by $index" class="inline_block name_container">
         <div class="inline_block aw_div_first">
          <label>College/University/Board:</label><br>
          <input class="form-control pd-forms" type="text"  ng-model="d.college" placeholder="College/University/Board"/>
         </div>
         <div class="inline_block aw_div">
          <label>Qualification:</label><br>
          <input class="form-control pd-forms" type="text"  ng-model="d.qual" placeholder="Qualification"/>
         </div> 
         <div class="btn btn-primary inline_block aw_button" ng-click="home.addDegree($index, d)" ng-if="$index === home.degrees.length - 1">+</div>
         <div class="btn btn-primary inline_block aw_button" ng-click="home.removeDegree($index)" ng-if="($index <= home.degrees.length - 1) && home.degrees.length > 1">-</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.degrees = [{college:'a',qual:'at'},{college:'b',qual:'bt'}]; //initialising array with one element to show one row initially

vm.addDegree = function(i, data){  
console.log(data);
            var degree ={};
            degree.college = 'test';
             degree.qual = 'testq';
          //  degree.year = data.year;
          //  vm.degrees[i] = degree;
            vm.degrees.push(degree);
            console.log("current degrees : ", vm.degrees);
        }

       vm.removeDegree = function(i){
         console.log(i);   
            vm.degrees.splice(i,1);
            console.log(vm.degrees);
        }
});
```

Comment: Plunker Not working, removal sign is not working... I have issues with remove only. Addition is working fine for me

Comment: Check now, change function to vm. vm.removeDegree = function(i){}

Comment: Tried this..This still shows the same issue. U click remove sign on first entry, its removing the last entry. To better see it, try entering data on each field and then click remove

Comment: Great. The way I wanted, But could not see any considerable change in the code. Additionally, My use case is to bind the data of input boxes in the `degrees` array. While clicking ADD, a blank row should be added and later this data should bind at that index....Is not that possible ??

Comment: Change in html page

Comment: You can blank degre data object to array , like this 
var degree ={};
            degree.college = '';
             degree.qual = '';

Comment: Still looking at it, sure will accept it, if it provides any help :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/6mbGKDPcE0o6aZoCyER0?p=preview , check this.. a button added , you can add new row into it and type college and degree there, click on button, I consoled there the array of degrees.